# XNA - Autodeploy .exe of game upon succesfull commit to GIT

Tags: c#, xna-4.0, automation, build-process

I know of ClickOnce which creates an .exe file so a user can play my XNA game.

However, I have to manually go through a wizard in order to create this file.

I would like for the new .exe to be created upon a successful commit of the code to GIT (ie. all my tests pass and the build succeeds) and for this file to be deployed on my Amazon AWS server so users can instantly download the 'new version' each commit.

Is this possible? I've been taking a look at Jenkins which seems to do what I want (Automated builds) but seems as though it's only for JAVA software.

Thanks for any info :)

Comment: There is normally an .exe file in Debug/bin folder that works as a standalone version of your game as long as the user has .NET installed.

Comment: How would I go about moving this .exe to my server upon a successful GIT commit? Is it possible to do such a thing? :/

Comment: Ive never done something like this myself,  but I think your best bet would be to manually upload it every once in a while

Comment: Using the .exe in the Debug/bin folder doesn't work. If I move it from the directory it is in and try to run it it just doesn't start the program.

Comment: Make sure you copy all dlls in the bin/Debug folder along with the exe

Answer (score 1):

You want a git post-commit or post-push hook to invoke your build chain automatically every-time those things happen.

http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks

(Or you could use Jenkins? Same thing, but more complex. Though you might like those features.)

Simply google "automated clickonce" to see that click once is not intended to be automated. You need another tool for that. msbuild, which is what visual studio uses internally, can build visual studio projects on the command line.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1841435/is-it-possible-to-automate-a-clickonce-deployment

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6319274/how-do-i-run-msbuild-from-the-command-line-using-windows-sdk-7-1